# Query- Data Conversion

Tags: ms-access, vba

`Term 1 - Time in Office(yrs)`  is a double number with data like 1.08618331053352 on my table and there are `NULL`s also.

I want to make this data into 1.0861 and for `NULL`s to be empty.

**Query:**

```
IIF ([Term 1- Time in Office(yrs)] <> "", Format ([Term 1- Time in Office(yrs)], "0.0000"))
```

I got error saying:

> Data type mismatch in criteria expression

Comment: Since this is a number you shouldn't check for empty string `""`.  Try `IIf([Term 1- Time in Office(yrs)] > 0, Round([Term 1- Time in Office(yrs)], 4), Null)`

Comment: I'd add an `Nz` to the answer by @KostasK., to avoid `Invalid use of null` errors, and compare with <> instead of > (`IIf(Nz([Term 1- Time in Office(yrs)]) <> 0, Format ([Term 1- Time in Office(yrs)], "0.0000"), Null)`)

Answer (score 0):

*Null* is not a string. Thus, check for Null and return this, as Format cannot return Null:

```
IIf([Term 1- Time in Office(yrs)] Is Null, Null, Format(Nz([Term 1- Time in Office(yrs)], 0), "0.0000"))
```